# Can a Primary Key be a Non Clusterd Index on a Clustered Table?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, clustered-index, database-design

I am designing a Members Table to store the users of a website. It will be used every time a user logs on to the website and occasionally accessed to update user details.

The users will log on with an email address and password and every account will have a unique email address. Therefore it seems logical that the Email column of the Members Table should be it's clustered index as the majority of queries on this table will be against the Email column as users log on. Making the Email column unique and the key to the clustered index should make querying user's data as they log on fast and improve performance.

But as I understand it, it would be wrong to make the Email column the Primary Key for two reasons. One, a Primary Key should be constant, so if a user decided to change their email address then all foreign keys would have to be updated and that would be bad. Secondly email addresses are strings which would make Joins slower than if the PK was an int.

So can I make a Non Clustered Index the Primary Key? So that the table has both a Clustered Index with Email as it's unique key, and an int primary key as a Non Clustered index on top?

Thanks,
Duncan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Primary key is a logical database design and only has to be unique and non-NULL (which is implemented with an index).

In addition, you have a choice of a single clustered index, which should be narrow, unique, increasing and static (email is probably NOT good for this).

I would make an IDENTITY int primary key and cluster on that.

I would add a unique non-clustered index on email and "include" additional columns so that your most frequent heavy queries become covering (i.e. the password hash).  Note that you should not need to add the clustered key to the included columns, since that is always included as the bookmark in the non-clustered index).

Look at the execution plans to ensure that you are not seeing any table scans or clustered index scans in the user table.

I would add that typically people think that seeing queries use a clustered index is a good thing. I would argue that a non-clustered index scan or seek used in a query where the indexes are covering is just as good on a heap (a table without a clustered index) as on a clustered index and better than a clustered index scan or seek. I would also argue that a clustered index is a name which leads people to all kinds of assumptions about things (to start with, it's not really an index on a table, it indicates that the table is stored completely in the index structure) and misconceptions about its importance.  Clustered indexes are most important in very large operations where a large amount of data is needed in the order of clustering.

Real (read) query speed on typical OLTP queries comes from covering the query with the narrowest possible non-clustered indexes on all the tables in the query with every column in the appropriate order and correct sort direction for the query/parameters.

Comment: +1 e-mail seems like a particularly poor clustered index to me

Comment: +1 And also http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/post/The-Clustered-Index-Debate-Continues.aspx

Comment: @gbn the sqlskills link should just automatically appear any time someone asks about clustered indexes on SO.

Comment: @Cade Roux Thanks for your reply, I still don't understand why an email address would make a bad clustered index key though. Why does it need to be narrow? The user data is still going to be looked up nearly all the time by the email whether it is a clustered index key or a nonclustered index key so the same computing is going to be required either way, only if it is a nonclustered index key then once the user is found in that index it will have to be looked up again in the clusered index. What is the benefit of an int PK if the data is only accessed through it 5% of the time?

Comment: @FunkyFresh84, the index points to the location of the data. In an over-simplified way, the *clustered* index will speed up retrieval of **sequential** rows because they're **physically** "next to each other". It will not make retrieving data from the *single* pointer any faster.

Comment: @FunkyFresh84 You want your non-clustered indexes to be covering, and yes, they can also be fragmented.  Typically DBAs are fine with defragging indexes, but not moving data around.  For small n, you don't have to worry too much about these things, but when you get to millions of rows, Kim Tripp's articles are correct.  Narrow (preferably fixed) so that the space used in all other indexes for the clustering key is not large, increasing to reduce page splits, unique so a uniquifier isn't added to the bookmarks on top of your key, static to reduce page splits/fragmentation.

Comment: @FunkyFresh84 Also, note that you are hopefully going to retrieve in a single set-based SQL operation, joining things as necessary to the PK, not getting the PK from the email and then going get other things from your client code.  In these cases, the internal surrogate PK may not be exposed in most (perhaps any) result sets.

Comment: Cade Roux, Matthew PK, gbn and ck thank you all for your excellent help. I have learnt a lot in a short space of time there and I shall read Kim Tripp's blogg and take a look around sqlskills right now!

Answer (score 3):

You absolutely can make a non-clustered index into the primary key.

However, I contend that you have it backwards a bit.
The e-mail address will make a particularly BAD clustered index because it's not inherently ordered. As the table grows you will lose `INSERT` performance due to page-splits, re-ordered, etc.

As @Cade Roux said, I would make the autonum the clustered index, enforce uniqueness on the e-mail address.

**EDIT:** The clustered index represents how data is *physically* stored on disk. Non-sequential clustered indices will hurt `INSERT` performance as data must be re-ordered (causing page-splits).
For *scanning for single rows* in a users table, you will likely find negligible difference between a clustered and non-clustered index. However, pursuant to the excellent link posted by @gbn, you *might* have better performance on range selects because the data is sequential. Nonetheless, I would personally have to really ponder a decision to use strings (or any inherently un-ordered data) for a clustered index.

**EDIT2:** One exceptional case I can think of would be if you commonly select chunks of users by e-mail address alphabetically... you'd still have slower `INSERT`s but you should be able to retrieve these groupings faster... As @Cade Roux said in the comments though: you should **not** expect single-row `SELECT`s to be more performant due to the clustered index.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I don't understand how an email is not inherently ordered. Surely if it was the clustered index key then looking users up by email would be like searching a dictionary. Maybe inserts would be slower but surely lookups would be faster?

Comment: @FunkyFresh84 the clustered index reflects how data is *physically* stored on disk. This is the same reason that unordered guids don't make good clustered indices. Say a user creates a@example.com, then a second user creates c@example.com... a third user creates b@example.com... the clustered index must re-order the data to perform the insert. This is in contrast to an autonumber where the new record just goes last in the clustered-index. The same B-Tree will be built for the index; there is no need to cluster on e-mail

Comment: @FunkyFresh84 The lookup would be faster with a clustered index seek/scan than a table scan, but a non-clustered index seek is almost always faster because a NCI fits more rows per page

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can.  When you create the table, set the columns like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Members
(
  ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(10000,1),
  Email Varchar(200) NOT NULL CONSTRAINT pk_Members PRIMARY KEY NONCLUSTERED,
  Otherstuff ...
)

CREATE CLUSTERED INDEX cdx_Members ON Members(ID)
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, This answers my question. Except I meant that Email should be the clustered index key and that Int should be the the Non Clustered PK. Do you have any comments on that?